# Sqoop import as Avro error

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, avro, hortonworks-data-platform

Stack : Installed HDP-2.3.2.0-2950 using Ambari 2.1

I am trying to import a sql server table onto HDFS.

```
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$ sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://dbserver;database=dbname' --username someusername --password somepassword --as-avrodatafile  --table DimSampleDesc --warehouse-dir /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016 --verbose
```

There is one error in the output :

```
Writing Avro schema file: /tmp/sqoop-sqoop/compile/bbbd98974f09b50a9335cedde30f73a5/DimSampleDesc.avsc
16/05/09 13:09:00 DEBUG mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob: Could not move Avro schema file to code output directory.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Destination directory '.' does not exist [createDestDir=true]
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:2865)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob.writeAvroSchema(DataDrivenImportJob.java:146)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob.configureMapper(DataDrivenImportJob.java:92)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:260)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager.importTable(SQLServerManager.java:163)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
```

The contents of /tmp/sqoop-sqoop/compile/bbbd98974f09b50a9335cedde30f73a5/ :

```
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$ ls -lrt /tmp/sqoop-sqoop/compile/bbbd98974f09b50a9335cedde30f73a5/
total 104
-rw-r--r--. 1 sqoop hadoop 61005 May  9 13:08 DimSampleDesc.java
-rw-r--r--. 1 sqoop hadoop 28540 May  9 13:08 DimSampleDesc.class
-rw-r--r--. 1 sqoop hadoop  9568 May  9 13:08 DimSampleDesc.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 sqoop hadoop  3659 May  9 13:09 DimSampleDesc.avsc
```

The contents of the warehouse-dir :

```
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$ hadoop fs -ls /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - sqoop hdfs          0 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$ hadoop fs -ls /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc
Found 7 items
-rw-r--r--   3 sqoop hdfs          0 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 sqoop hdfs       2660 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00000.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 sqoop hdfs    5039870 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00001.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 sqoop hdfs    1437143 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00002.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 sqoop hdfs    1486327 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00003.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 sqoop hdfs     595550 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00004.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 sqoop hdfs       4792 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00005.avro
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$
```

I then copied the avsc and other files manually.

```
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/sqoop-sqoop/compile/d039c1b0b2a2b224d65943df1de34cdd/* /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/
```

Now all files in one place :

```
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$ hadoop fs -ls /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/
Found 11 items
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs       3659 2016-05-09 13:49 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/DimSampleDesc.avsc
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs      28540 2016-05-09 13:49 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/DimSampleDesc.class
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs       9568 2016-05-09 13:49 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/DimSampleDesc.jar
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs      61005 2016-05-09 13:49 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/DimSampleDesc.java
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs          0 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/_SUCCESS
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs       2660 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00000.avro
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs    5039870 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00001.avro
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs    1437143 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00002.avro
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs    1486327 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00003.avro
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs     595550 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00004.avro
-rw-rw-rw-   3 sqoop hdfs       4792 2016-05-09 13:09 /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/part-m-00005.avro
```

Now I created the Hive table and described it:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE DimSampleDesc  ROW FORMAT SERDE  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'  STORED as INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'  OUTPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'  TBLPROPERTIES (    'avro.schema.url'='hdfs://l1031lab.sss.se.com:8020/dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/DimSampleDesc.avsc');
OK
Time taken: 0.166 seconds
hive>
hive>
    > describe formatted DimSampleDesc;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment


smapiname_ver           string
smapicolname            string
charttype               int
x_indexet               int
y_indexet               int
x_tick                  string
y_tick                  string
x_tickrange             string
x_tickrangefrom         string
x_tickrangetom          string
y_tickrange             string
y_tickrangefrom         string
y_tickrangetom          string
indexcount              int
x_indexcount            int
y_indexcount            int
x_symbol                string
x_symbolname            string
x_symboldescr           string
y_symbol                string
y_symbolname            string
y_symboldescr           string
smapiname               string
incorrect_ver_fl        boolean


# Detailed Table Information
Database:               odp_dw_may2016
Owner:                  hive
CreateTime:             Mon May 09 14:46:40 CEST 2016
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://l1031lab.sss.se.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/odp_dw_may2016.db/dimsampledesc
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE
Table Parameters:
        COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false
        EXTERNAL                TRUE
        avro.schema.url         hdfs://l1031lab.sss.se.com:8020/dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/DimSampleDesc.avsc
        numFiles                0
        numRows                 -1
        rawDataSize             -1
        totalSize               0
        transient_lastDdlTime   1462798000


# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        serialization.format    1
Time taken: 0.416 seconds, Fetched: 56 row(s)
hive>
    >
```

But no data found :

```
hive>
    >
    > select * from DimSampleDesc;
OK
Time taken: 0.098 seconds
hive>
```

The schema file :

```
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$ hadoop fs -cat /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/DimSampleDesc.avsc                                                                                   {
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "DimSampleDesc",
  "doc" : "Sqoop import of DimSampleDesc",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "SmapiName_ver",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "SmapiName_ver",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }, {
    "name" : "SmapiColName",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "SmapiColName",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }, {
    "name" : "ChartType",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "ChartType",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_Indexet",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_Indexet",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_Indexet",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_Indexet",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_Tick",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_Tick",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_Tick",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_Tick",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_TickRange",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_TickRange",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_TickRangeFrom",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_TickRangeFrom",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_TickRangeTom",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_TickRangeTom",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_TickRange",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_TickRange",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_TickRangeFrom",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_TickRangeFrom",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_TickRangeTom",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_TickRangeTom",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "IndexCount",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "IndexCount",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_IndexCount",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_IndexCount",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_IndexCount",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_IndexCount",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_Symbol",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_Symbol",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_SymbolName",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_SymbolName",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "X_SymbolDescr",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "X_SymbolDescr",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_Symbol",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_Symbol",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_SymbolName",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_SymbolName",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "Y_SymbolDescr",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Y_SymbolDescr",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "SmapiName",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "SmapiName",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }, {
    "name" : "Incorrect_Ver_FL",
    "type" : [ "null", "boolean" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "Incorrect_Ver_FL",
    "sqlType" : "-7"
  } ],
  "tableName" : "DimSampleDesc"
}[sqoop@l1038lab root]$
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$
```

What is the root cause and how do I proceed ?

Comment: From desc formatted, the table location is '/apps/hive/warehouse/odp_dw_may2016.db/dimsampledesc' but the datafiles are in /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc/
In your create table statement put location = ' /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016/DimSampleDesc' - that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same avroschema file that you get when you sqoop to create tables on top of it in hive. You can do that using avrotools.jar.

Check if you table in SQL Server has same data.

Comment: Yes, I moved the avsc file manually from the tmp dir. to the dir. where avro files are saved but this manual fix needs to be eliminated. How do I do that ?
The table is now created but select * from shows nothing ...

Comment: 'Use the same avroschema file that you get when you sqoop' was something I overlooked, thank you.

Comment: Hello, are you still getting the avro schema file from /tmp/ folder? Should not be created in the same folder that you run the sqoop import command?

Answer (score 0):

Change --warehouse-dir  to --target-dir in your sqoop import.

You have copied all java, jar and avro files to the same folder. Hive will like having different type of files in the same folder.